# Apple Pay integration with Angular

Tags: angular, applepay, angular12, applepayjs, payment-request-api

I want to integrate ApplePay and GooglePay in our Angular application.

For GooglePay, google has provided a useful package for npm. https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-pay/button-angular

I tried to find a similar good package for ApplePay but couldn't find any.

I want to implement ApplePay on Angular. There are two ways to implement it (JS API and Payment Request API) and I would like to use the API method as I want to do as much as processing in server side. By looking at the following page, it's hard to understand the difference between JS API and Payment Request API.
https://applepaydemo.apple.com/

Surprisingly I can't find any example code for Angular to use ApplePay. I can't believe no one has used ApplePay on Angular before. May be there is another/better way to do it?

In Angular it's even tricky to get the window instance. I have tried the solutions in this question and managed to inject window instance using a service provider. I can display the ApplePay button on appropriate devices but I am getting the following error when calling the ApplePaySession object. Apparenlty the injected window is not the top level one.

*Error: Trying to start an Apple Pay session from a document with an different security origin than its top-level frame.*

According to the [WebKit code](https://github.com/WebKit/webkit/blob/8afe31a018b11741abdf9b4d5bb973d7c1d9ff05/Source/WebCore/Modules/applepay/PaymentSession.cpp#L69), this is when it returns that error but not sure how to solve it.

```
 if (!ancestorDocument->securityOrigin().isSameSchemeHostPort(topOrigin))
      return Exception { InvalidAccessError, "Trying to start an Apple Pay session from a document with an different security origin than its top-level frame." };
```

Has anyone tried ApplePay on Angular or is there any sample code on how to bind to validation events from Angular? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a package that supports both payment types, I found the NPM package [ng-wallet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-wallet) for Angular. However, I wouldn't recommend using a package from an unofficial publisher. Google/Apple API changes might not be maintained by [ng-wallet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-wallet)'s publisher.

If you plan to maintain your Angular application long term, it is recommended to use packages that will have regular maintenance from Google/Apple:

- Google Pay - Use the official [Google Pay](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-pay/button-angular) package for Angular.
- Apple Pay - Apple haven't published an NPM package for Apple Pay yet. Using a third-party publisher's packages may cause problems mentioned above. Your best option is to implement it yourself using their [Apple Pay JS](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apple_pay_on_the_web/apple_pay_js_api) API.

**Keep in mind that Apple only supports ApplePay on Safari.**